# Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Tags: 16.04, server, upstart

in etc/init I put a .conf file:

```
# -*- upstart -*-
# Upstart configuration script for WordVectServer

description "WordVectServer"
kill timeout 5

pre-start script
mkdir -p /var/log/wordvecServer/
sleep 10 
end script

exec sudo WordVectServer server /home/marco/WVLoader/src/G.bin >> 
/var/log/wordvecServer/wordvecServer.log

start on runlevel [2345]
```

and made it executable with

```
sudo chmod +x wordvecServer.conf
```

But when trying to launch the execution:

```
marco@PC:/etc/init$ sudo start sudo chmod +x wordvectServer
[sudo] password for marco:
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket 
/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

marco@PC:~$ sudo apt-get install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
upstart is already the newest version (1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

So...what to do to solve the problem? Any hints?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: 16.04 uses systemd, write a systemd unit instead. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: Thank @muru . What I do not understand is why I should use systemd if before I had to re-install 16.04 I used upstart in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: for a user session, perhaps. Ubuntu is on systemd since 15.04, so I'd say you should double check whatever you thought you saw.

Comment: I think I made a BIG mistake... following what is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers "Permanent switch back to upstart
Install the upstart-sysv package, which will remove ubuntu-standard and systemd-sysv (but should not remove anything else -- if it does, yell!), and run sudo update-initramfs -u."     I installed upstart-sysv package, and now on rebooting... "EXT4-f remounted. Opts: errors = remount-ro" ...